# Running tkinter Tests on a Device without a Display

Tags: python, tkinter, testing, gitlab-ci-runner

I have some Python code that I created some tkinter GUI's for. I wrote some basic tests for some of the custom frames that make up these GUI's using the pytest framework and they work locally. However, I have this project hosted on a GitLab repository which uses a runner to automatically run these tests, and the runner has no display, causing the tests to fail. Specifically, they fail when creating the frame's master, which must be a Tk object. When initializing the Tk object, the following line in the tkinter source code fails due to a Tcl error:

`self.tk = _tkinter.create(...)`

I do not need to actually display the widgets, I just want to test that nothing breaks when initializing them and using their methods. I have tried mocking both the Frame class (same error as before) and the Tk class (`Mock object has no attribute 'tk'`), to no success. I am wondering if there is a means of getting these tests to run on the runner, or if I should just have the tests skip when there is no display. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have a display of some sort to run a tk-based app, there is no getting around that. If you are using an X11-based system (eg: linux) you can accomplish this by running the app inside a virtual frame buffer (eg: xvfb) or a docker container running X11.